# Unterschied zwischen den Adjektivierungen mit Endungen -ig und -haft. Konkret: Wann nutzt man „eklig“, wann „ekelhaft“?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

Selbst wenn ich deren Übersetzungen lese und sie miteinander vergleiche, ist mir nicht so verständlich, wann man *eklig* und wann man *ekelhaft* nutzt. Beide sind doch Adjektive und beide stammen von *Ekel*.

Laut [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Suffixe/haft.html?country=D) komme `-haft` häufiger bei der Adjektivisierung von Nomen vor als bei der von Verben. Aber die gleiche Quelle fügt nichts Passendes zur Endung `-ig` hinzu (die praktisch allgegenwärtig ist).

**Frage:** Wie wirkt denn jede Endung?

**Hinweise**: Meine Interesse liegt nicht an diesem Adjektiv, sondern an der Möglichkeit, ein zweites Adjektiv mit der Endung `-haft` zu bilden. D. h. die Frage gilt für andere Adjektive (die ich jetzt leider nicht erinnere).

Comment: Hm. Bei den beiden Worten sehe ich keinen Unterschied. Ein anderes Beispiel hingegen hat leichte Unterschiede: *sündig* vs *sündhaft*. Wobei ich es nicht in Worte fassen kann. (Und ich beziehe mich hier nicht auf die zweite Definition von *sündhaft*, die ja deutlich anders ist.) Wiederum andere Beispiele unterscheiden sich deutlich: *gläubig* und *glaubhaft*. Tricky question auf jeden Fall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt zwar keine allgemeingültige Regel, wie das Suffix **-ig** gegenüber **-haft** die Bedeutung eines daraus gebildeten Adjektivs beeinflusst. Insbesondere bei solchen Adjektiven, bei denen beide Formen nebeneinander stehen, hilft es aber ein wenig, sich mit der Etymologie der Suffixe zu beschäftigen:

---

### [-haft](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=-haft)

> […] geht hervor aus dem gemeingerm., noch in den älteren dt. Sprachstufen lebendigen selbständigen Verbaladjektiv ahd. (9. Jh.), mhd. *haft*, asächs. *haft, haht* ‘**gebunden, gefangen**’, mit Gen. ‘schwanger’ (mhd., vereinzelt noch frühnhd. auch ‘**eingenommen, besetzt**’, mit Dat. ‘**verbunden**, **verpflichtet**’), aengl. *hæft* ‘**gefangen**’, got. *hafts* ‘**behaftet**’ (vgl. anord. *haptr* ‘Gefangener, Leibeigener’).

In der Verwendung bedeutet dies also grob und als Faustregel, dass damit eine Eigenschaft beschrieben wird, mit der etwas oder jemand **behaftet** oder damit **eng verbunden** ist.

---

### -[ig](http://homepages.uni-tuebingen.de/henrike.laehnemann/suffixe.htm#ig)

> Evtl. von dem lat. Adj.suffix *–is* abgeleitet; neben *–isc* für viele Adjektivneubildungen verwendet, z.b. *burtig* (gebürtig) zu *gipurt*, *thurftig* (bedürfig) zu *thurft* (Bedürftigkeit, vgl. noch 'Notdurft'), *wirdig* (würdig) zu *wirdi* (Würde).

Diese Adjektivbildung ist somit wohl die älteste und sehr häufig. Damit erscheint eine damit verbundene besondere Bedeutung nicht wahrscheinlich.

---

### [-lich](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=-lich)

> das mit dem in Leiche, gleich (s. d.) enthaltenen Substantiv germ. **līka-* ‘**Körper, Gestalt**’ identisch ist. Dieses Kompositionselement bildet im Germ. mit Adjektiven, Adverbien, Partikeln und persönlichen Substantiven Possessivkomposita im Sinne von ‘**die Gestalt, die Beschaffenheit habend**’, vgl. got. *waíraleikō* Adv. ‘männlich’, eigentl. ‘den Körper, die Gestalt, die Beschaffenheit eines Mannes habend’, ahd. *wīblīh* ‘weiblich’, eigentl. ‘die Gestalt einer Frau habend’.

Diese Suffigierung wird also dann gebraucht, wenn man eine Beschaffenheit oder Gestalt im Ganzen ausdrücken möchte.

---

Interessanterweise gibt es aber durchaus auch Kombinationen mit diesen Suffixen, insbesondere dann, wenn wieder ein Nomen gebildet wird (z. B. *Boshaftigkeit*, *Glaubhaftigkeit*).

---

Für das Beispiel *ekelhaft/eklig* könnte man also Folgendes postulieren:

- **eklig:** eine Sache, dem der Ekel innewohnt, der aus seiner Gesamtheit dazu geeignet ist, Ekel zu erregen.
- **ekelhaft:** eine Sache, der etwas Ekel auslösendes anhaftet, dessen äußere Eigenschaften Ekel erregen.

Diese Unterschiede sind aber eher hypothetischer Natur und im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch kaum zu erkennen. Man kann durchaus *eklig* und *ekelhaft* synonym verwenden.

Comment: *-ig*: Wie eine Sache erscheinen. Etwas suggerieren. "Das Kind ist goldig" => Es besteht nicht aus Gold. Es vermittelt nur den Anschein, aufgrund seines liebenswerten Verhaltens. // "Das Essen sieht eklig aus" => Es sieht unappetlich aus. Kann aber durchaus lecker sein.

Comment: *haft* könnte auch in *heftig* "heavy" gesehen werden, vgl auch *Steuern erheben*, *Ekel erregend*. Sofern En *eek!* verwandt ist, wäre *-l* wohl ein Suffix, bzw *-lig*. Danach erscheint *Ekel[-haft]* wie eine sekundäre Ableitung.

Answer (score 4):

*Eklig* kann eine Sache sein, Dinge die man nicht angreifen möchte, oder eine Person wenn sie äußerlich ungepflegt ist:

> Herr X ist nett aber eklig. Beim Vorlesen hängt ihm der ... aus der Nase. =)

Das Adjektiv *ekelhaft* würde ich hauptsächlich für eine Person mit schlechtem Charakter benutzen:

> Frau A ist wirklich eine ekelhafte Person. Sie hat Frau B auf der Straße 'Schlampe' nachgerufen!

Answer (score 4):

Auf den ersten Blick scheinen *eklig* und *ekelhaft* gleichbedeutend zu sein.  Aber ihre Bedeutung liegt doch so nah beieinander, dass ich mir vorstellen kann, das so manches Lexikon
den Unterschied im Gebrauch nicht vermitteln kann. Ich schließe mich der Meinung von iSi an und würde sagen, *eklig* sind Dinge, die man nicht anfassen möchte.

Eine Frau könnte sagen:

> Mir ekelt vor Kröten, ich kann sie nicht anfassen. Ich finde sie eklig.

*Ekelhaft* würde ich auf das Benehmen eines Menschen beziehen. Wenn Herr M. seiner Frau am Morgen  eine ungalante Bemerkung macht, könnte sie erbittert sagen:

> Du bist ekelhaft.

Hier würde *eklig* nicht passen.

Es dürfte aber Bereiche geben, wo beide Adjektive ohne großen Unterschied gebraucht werden. Um das zu entscheiden, wären aber eingehende Studien notwendig.

Ich glaube nicht, dass es viele Adjektivpaare mit `-ig/-haft` gibt und vor allem glaube ich nicht, dass man  analog dazu selbst neue Adjektivpaare bilden kann.

PS: Man kann sagen, *mir/mich ekelt etwas*. Das ist ein unsicherer Bereich, wo der Gebrauch schwankt.