# Adjective endings: -isch, -lich or -ig?

Tags: adjective, suffix

I am in my first year studying German, and I couldn't not notice that some adjectives form from nouns with *-ig* (e.g. *salzig, vorsichtig*), others with *-lich* (*monatlich, sommerlich* etc.), and others with *-isch* (*typisch, telefonisch*). Is there a rule defining which ending to use when?

Comment: Partly related answer to a different question (in German): http://german.stackexchange.com/a/11347/15318 Not a true duplicate imho, because that one asks for a specific difference of two words, and for a different ending, too.

Comment: Also partially related to this one (in German, about the etymology): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10627/verwandtschaft-von-lich-ig-etc

Answer (score 16):

There is no clear-cut rule. Any rule I am about to lay out now has a dozen exceptions to it. But a few similarities do stike me once I try to think about the suffixes.

First, *-isch* is the only element in your list that can be added to geographical places:

> *türkisch, italienisch, europäisch, wienerisch, hessisch, …*

*-isch* is also used to detonate the means of doing something:

> *postalisch, telefonisch, technisch, lautmalerisch*

and that probably also sums up adjectives from scientific disciplines, although I can't pinpoint it directly:

> *medizinisch, chemisch, geographisch, altphilologisch*

*-lich*, according to the etymologies linked in the comments under the question, derives from an old and obsolete word for *body* and shares a common root with *Leiche* (corpse). So it originally meant *something, whose body/shape was of kind x*.

> *sommerlich* (as in summer), *merklich* (can be realised), *deutlich* (can be heard), *willentlich* (made of free will), *männlich* (like a man), …

The suffix can also be used much like the English *-ish* but not with many adjectives:

> *gräulich, bläulich, ärmlich, …*

because with others it will create a new word with a different meaning:

> *kleinlich*

It's also productive to give *every <timeframe>*:

> *täglich, monatlich, wöchentlich, zweiwöchentlich, stündlich, jährlich, augenblicklich*

But note that these can also be connected with *-ig*:

> *zweiwöchig*

The difference is: Something that is *zweiwöchig* will take two weeks and then be finished; e.g. an internship. Something that is *zweiwöchentlich* happens every other week, e.g. a football team's home match.

*-ig* is probably the most productive of the three (unless you count every single geographic entity on earth, in which case *-isch* might win), because it was used as a suffix in very early Germanic times. It is *the* suffix to turn a word into an adjective meaning *of this type*:

> *rosig, glasig, farbig, wässrig, grasig, lausig, gängig, sonnig, schnittig, putzig, witzig, schokoladig, teilweisig, …*

If you want to create a new word, your best bet is *-ig*. It is also the only one that can turn adverbs into adjectives (usually *-weise*-adverbs).

And here is where it gets complicated. You can get pairs of adjectives with different suffixes:

> *geschäftlich* – *geschäftlicher Besuch* is a visitor from a company who's probably going to try and sell you something.
> *geschäftig* – *geschäftiger Besuch* is a visitor who just can't stop doing stuff; whatever "stuff" is.
>
> *telefonisch* – by telephone
> *telefonig* – something that looks like a telephone, but is not.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Jan is already very good.
For the sake of completeness, I’d like to translate / summarize / quote what the Duden has to say on this exact topic ([Adjektive auf -ig, -isch, -lich](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Adjektive-auf-ig-isch-lich)):

The ending *-ig* means that the denoted characteristic is present:

> *nebelig* = there is actual fog

The ending *-isch* is often used to build adjectives from living things / people, and then means “in the fashion of an *x*”:

> *diebisch* / *künstlerisch* = in the fashion of a thief / artist

But *-isch* is also used to form adjectives from other nouns and then means that something “belongs to *x*”:

> *grammatisch* / *griechisch* = belongs to the realm of grammar / Greece

Words ending in *-lich* are the most neutral and tend to just mean *has something to do with X*:

> *ärztlich* = has to do with a physician.

Jan already pointed out that the same base noun can have different adjectival suffixes to denote different attributes.
In addition to his elaboration, Duden has the following:

If two adjectives are built from the same noun, one with *-lich* and one with *-isch*, then *-lich* **usually** just denotes that something belongs to *x*, whereas *-isch* has a pejorative connotation:

> All *Bauern* are *bäuerlich*, because they pertain to the category of peasants, but not all of them are *bäurisch*, because they are not necessarily country bumpkins.