# Difference between “farbig”, “farblich” and “bunt”

Tags: difference, usage, adjective

I am trying to understand if there are differences in the way people use these three adjectives: *farbig, farblich* and *bunt*.
So far as I know:

- *bunt* = coloured (a dress, a bird …), lively (an afternoon, an event);
- *farbig* = coloured (a glass, a person);
- *farblich* = coloured.

I am not really able, expect for the specific examples above, which I found on Duden, to distinguish and know when is best to use one or the other adjective. 
What is the diffence in usage between those three?

Comment: _Farblich_ is the odd man out because it means _pertaining to the colour_, _in terms of colour_. It can’t mean _coloured_ like the other words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, there is a mildly related question on the topic of [when adjectives use *-lich* and when *-ig*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/adjective-endings-isch-lich-or-ig). So I’ll start with those two.

**Farblich,** as was noted in the question’s comments, is clearly an odd one out here, and it is the one I would least translate with *coloured*. The suffix *-lich* can often be traced back to an old and obsolete word for *body*; therefore, *farblich* is a lot more *on the topic of the colours present*.

> Das passt *farblich* nicht zusammen.
>   These colours do not match. (literally: This doesn’t fit together by colours)

**Farbig** uses the suffix *-ig* which declares the type of something. Thus, if something is *farbig*, it contains colours. You can specify which colours but it can just generally mean *contains a colour*, too.

> Das eine Bild ist *farbig*, das andere ist schwarz-weiß.
>   One of the photos is coloured, the other is black and white.

You can also easily create compounds with *farbig*, for example *zweifarbig, mehrfarbig, …* meaning *two-coloured, multicoloured* etc.

**Bunt** is closely related to coloured, but actually means *colourful*. If something only has one colour, no matter how bright it is, I wouldn’t call it *bunt*. Also, if there are multiple colours present, but they are similar shades of one another, or are maybe all pastellish in tone, I would be hesitant with the word. Something that has two distinct colours (red and yellow, for example) can be called bunt. Note that all of the objects I ‘described’ could have been called *farbig* (because they have at least one colour).

> Bilderbücher oder Bauklötze für Kinder sind meistens sehr bunt.
>   Picture books or building bricks for children are usually rather colourful.
>
> Der [Eisvogel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisvogel) ist ein sehr bunter Vogel — viele Papageien sind aber bunter.
>   The [kingfisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_kingfisher) is a pretty colourful bird — many parrots are more colourful, though.

According to TaW’s comment, in the specialised context of printing apparantly *bunte Farben* can refer to actual colours while *unbunte Farben* means greyscale — in case you ever come across that.

Comment: In the context of printing you can also have 'bunte Farben' and 'unbunte Farben', the latter being grey scale colors.

Comment: I think you also use "bunt" for a classroom which has several students from different countries

Comment: @user1474062 Well technically yes, but I explicitly did not touch any metaphoric uses. And I actively disprove of using *bunt* in that context since it implies people have ‘colours’. If anything, I would use *bunt* for a classroom with many hippies in contrast to *schwarz* for a classroom with many metalheads.

Answer (score 5):

*Bunt* in this context means that something has multiple colors, I think *colorful* should mostly match it’s meaning. In everyday use, it’s a bit subjective how colorful something needs to be, eg. [this building](http://deutschland.yakohl.com/pic/buntes-haus--2292012.jpg) surely is *bunt*, but [this one](http://dongowski-hauskonzepte.de/upload/CY6ae9bea5X1239d9d2be4XY5e91/1252482258041/Abele_klein.jpg) may not be.
Uses unrelated to colors includes your example of *lively*,
and *Es wird mir zu bunt* roughly means *This becomes too much for me [so stop that]*

*Farbig* can be used to express what color something has:

> My bike is red <=> Mein Fahrrad ist rotfarbig.

although it usually can be omitted in such cases

> My bike is red <=> Mein Fahrrad ist rot.

It can express how many colors something has (e.g. *zweifarbig*).
Lastly, *farbig* (alone) can also mean *not black/white*

And *farblich* expresses stuff related to the color itself, e.g.

> Diese Drucke sind farblich verschieden <=> These printouts differ in terms of colors

Opposed to that

> Diese Drucke sind verschieden

just means that the printouts are somehow different, and

> Diese Drucke sind farbig verschieden

would mean that the difference has a color
(altough people will understand what you mean)