# -isch adjective ending and instrumentality

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective, adjective-ending, suffix

Firstly, I apologise if I am completely off mark, as I am trying to teach myself German whilst simultaneously being rather new to it.

I was trying to better understand adjectival suffixes, and found [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/adjective-endings-isch-lich-or-ig) post to be particularly useful.

What particularly caught my eye was the explanation concerning the use of the ending -isch, to denote a means of something.

Having previously encountered languages with an instrumental case, I can't help but draw similarities, and was wondering whether the ending could be employed thusly.

For example, would it be correct to translate 'Hans writes with a pen' as

> Hans stiftisch schreibt.

?

I particularly choose this sentence as [a relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case) instead provides

> Hans schreibt mit einem Stifte.

as the appropriate translation.

For me this raises two questions:

1. Am I correct with my translation, or simply overzealous with my use of the *-isch* ending?
2. If my translation is accurate, how common is it for a native German speaker to also use the same approach?

Comment: As a native speaker I'm having trouble following your reasoning. Even if I try to correct the verb conjugation and the word order to "Hans schreibt stiftisch.", the translation is not correct and probably wouldn't be understood by most native speakers. "stiftisch" is simply not a German word.

Comment: @Roland I see. so there is no freedom to add suffixes to adjectives, or is this specifically with -isch and doesn't apply to other suffixes such as -ig?

Comment: Hm, *Hans schreibt händisch.* would work. *Händisch* means *by hand*. (So he is not writing using a computer or typewriter.) But unfortunately your approach doesn't work.

Comment: As you might know, adjectives derived from nouns end on -lich, -ig, -haft, -sam, -isch, -ern. Rules regarding when each of these is used have so many exceptions that I wouldn't bother with them. Most adjectives have already been derived. New adjectives are rare (and often related to new nouns, which mostly are loan words). "stiftisch" is not a word that exists already and I don't think a native speaker would build it. It is clearly not needed on your example because we would just use *mit* + dative case.

Comment: This page list some examples and corresponding suffixes in other languages. Interestingly, for Russian it shows an adjective suffix, not an instrumental case suffix. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-isch

Comment: @ArmelFrançois: Roland hat nicht ganz recht. Das ein Wort im Deutschen nicht existiert kann man so pauschal oft nicht sagen, denn die dt. Sprache ist plastisch und es gehört zu ihrem Wesen, dass sie solche spontanen Wortbildungen zulässt. Richtig ist, dass "stiftisch" vollkommen ungebräuchlich ist und vielleicht nicht verstanden wird. Die meisten Deutschen sind auch nicht kreativ genug, um selbst Wörter zu bilden und mutig genug, ein Wort zu benutzen, das sie noch nie gehört haben. Schriftsteller, Liedtexter u.a. tun es aber häufig und manchmal etablieren sich diese Neuschöpfungen dann auch.

Comment: Zu beachten ist auch, dass "Stift" mehrdeutig ist. Es kann ein Kloster/Priesterseminar bezeichnen (Domstift), ein Schreibwerkzeug (Bleistift, Buntstift) oder auch einen zylindrischen Körper (Metallstift, Holzstift) sowie einen Lehrling/Azubi (umgangssprachlich).

Comment: @userunknown Deine Auslassungen sind nicht besonders relevant für jemanden, der allenfalls grundlegende Deutschkenntnisse hat. Wenn ein Anfänger sich mit solchen Wortbildungen versucht, wird dies meist schiefgehen, nicht zuletzt, weil das gebildete Wort oft schon mit leicht anderer Bedeutung existiert. Wortschöpfungen durch Lyriker tun dabei nichts zur Sache.

Comment: @Olafant would it be possible to ask you to elaborate why händisch works but stiftisch doesn't, or is it matter of an acquired aesthetic understanding of the language through more ingrained use?

Comment: @fruitlessfruitjuice *Händisch* is established and has a fixed meaning while *stiftisch* is an ad-hoc creation and therefore a matter of interpretation.

Comment: @Roland: Gegen Deine Behauptung, stiftisch sei schlicht kein deutsches Wort, sprechen nicht nur ein paar Tausend Googletreffer (wenn auch in anderer Bedeutung), sondern auch die Tatsache, dass darunter viele Wörterbücher sind, die es alle für ein deutsches Wort halten. Dein Paternalismus, Anfänger vor Fehlern bewahren zu wollen, in allen Ehren, aber dazu sollte man keine Märchen erzählen. Jeder hat das Recht im Deutschen neue Wörter zu bilden, nicht nur Muttersprachler und Fortgeschrittene. Dass die dt. Sprache so etwas generell zulässt IST auch für Anfänger eine relevante Information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd say the basic idea that in German, you can form adjectives ad-hoc by attaching a suffix is right. However, it doesn't quite work the way you outline.

Let's go through your question sequentially, also including some tangential remarks:

As is already explained in the post you found, there are several common suffixes that can be attached to form adjectives (-isch, -ig, -lich), and the resulting meaning is not always clear-cut.

> For example, would it be correct to translate 'Hans writes with a pen' as: Hans stiftisch schreibt ?

Not really, and I don't really care that "stiftisch" cannot be found in a dictionary. First, word order should be different:

> Hans schreibt stiftisch.

Even then, this somehow conveys to me that Hans is writing *like* a pen, not *with* a pen. As stated before, there is no fixed rule for the resulting meaning, but by default, I'd say it always leans toward something vague like "like X", "related to X", rather than in particular "using X".

> I particularly choose this sentence as a relevant Wikipedia page instead provides: 'Hans schreibt mit einem Stifte' as the appropriate translation.

That sentence should read

> Hans schreibt mit dem Stift.

The form "Stifte" is not just "not used in most common conversation", it is completely outdated both in spoken and written German.

Therefore: Adjectives are not usually created by native German speakers to express anything like the instrumental case, but they *may* occasionally be formed to express other things.

Comment: Ich heraufstimme deine Antwort!

Comment: thank you for your answer, and the tangents you addressed, every bit of information is interesting to me :). however, there is something that I am a little confused about (perhaps a red herring): @Olafant seems to claim that 'Hans schreibt händisch' is correct. yet, using your explanation would seem to make this sentence: 'Hans writes like a hand', which seems a little peculiar. am I cometely on the wrong track?

Comment: @YetiCGN Auch wenn der Kontext es klar macht: 'heraufstimmen' würde niemand verwenden. "+1 für Deine Antwort", oder schön denglisch "Upvote für Deine Antwort".

Comment: @fruitlessfruitjuice: My explanation is only a good rule of thumb for custom adjectives formed ad-hoc. Established adjectives based on the same pattern (such as "händisch") can well have a different meaning.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper I see. so the adjectives need to be pre-established, else they most likely take your meaning. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Well, the sentence

> Hans stiftisch schreibt.

is completely wrong. No native speaker would even think of constructing such a sentence. Even worse: Nobody would understand it in the way you want it to be understood. It is wrong for two reasons:

1. There is no adjective *"stiftisch".* Even if you would use it grammatically correct (see next item), nobody would understand what you mean.
2. Adjectives which modify verbs always appear behind the verb:

> wrong: Hans schön schreibt.
> correct: Hans schreibt schön.

The sentence from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case)

> Hans schreibt mit einem Stifte.

is correct, but used an outdates dative ending. This is clearly mentioned in the Wikipedia article, but it sould be mentioned here too. This is correct in modern German:

> Hans schreibt mit einem Stift.

---

But let's imagine the word *»stiftisch«* would exist, and you would use it correctly (after the verb). Even then it would be understood as:

> Hans schreibt *stiftisch.*
> Hans is writing **like a** pen.

So, if this construction was a case, it would be an [equative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equative_case), not an [instrumental case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case), although Proto-Indo-European didn't have an equative case but an instrumental case which became extinct in German about 1000 years ago.

The understanding of *stiftisch* used the same pattern as:

> Hans schreibt *türkisch.*
> Hans writes Turkish. = Hans writes **like a** Turk.
> not: <del>Hans writes **with a** Turk.</del>

Comment: *Hans schreibt händisch.* would mean *Hans schreibt wie eine Hand.* according to your explanation.

Comment: Dein letztes Argument ist falsch, denn "Hans schreibt händisch" bedeutet ja auch nicht, Hans schreibt, als wäre er eine Hand. Mit solchen Ad-hoc-Regeln, die sich auf ein (in Zahlen: 1) Beispiel stützen, muss man vorsichtig sein und aktiv nach Gegenbeispielen suchen, sonst setzt man Unfug in die Welt, kommentiere ich spöttisch. Dein Beispiel mit "türkisch" hätte Dir das schon zeigen müssen - ein Türke kann auch auf deutsch antworten, "Der Türke antwortet türkisch" bedeutet also nicht "wie ein Türke".

Comment: @Olafant: Tut es nicht, und zwar genau deshalb, weil sich das Wort "händisch" bereits gewissermaßen etabliert hat, und zwar mit anderer Bedeutung als "wie eine Hand". Das ändert nichts daran, dass man heutzutage Adjektive, die sich noch *nicht* fest etabliert haben, und die ad-hoc durch Anhängen von -isch gebildet wurden, eher als "wie ein X" denn als "mit einem X" versteht.

Comment: @userunknown: 'ein Türke kann auch auf deutsch antworten, "Der Türke antwortet türkisch" bedeutet also nicht "wie ein Türke".' - sehe ich nicht so. Das sind freilich Abstraktionen. Natürlich können bestimmte Türken ohne Weiteres auch auf Deutsch, auf Japanisch oder auf Isländisch schreiben, und dabei vielleicht nicht einmal auf Türkisch. Das ändert nichts daran, dass ein "generischer, stereotyper" Türke wohl in türkischer Sprache schreiben wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Deshalb das Beispiel *türkisch*? "dass man heutzutage Adjektive, die sich noch nicht fest etabliert haben, und die ad-hoc durch Anhängen von -isch gebildet wurden, eher als *wie ein X* denn als *mit einem X* versteht", bezweifle ich stark.

Comment: @Olafant: Hast du Gegenbeispiele? Egal, an welche Substantive ich denke, so lange sich das durch Anhängen von -isch gebildete Adjektiv überhaupt natürlich anhört (Tisch - tischisch, Wolke - wolkisch, Kamel - kamelisch, Schrank - schränkisch, Topf - töpfisch ...), geben mir die Adjektive ausnahmslos den Eindruck, sie drücken ein "wie ein X" aus.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper *Adverb* ist das Stichwort! Ich esse tischisch. Ich reite kamelisch. Ich bewahre schränkisch auf. Ich koche töpfisch. Ich wohne wäldisch. ...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Von einem generischen (?), stereotypen Türken war aber nicht die Rede, vom Schreiben auch nicht. Deine Aussage ist ein Widerspruch in sich, denn für einen Ausdruck, der sich noch nicht fest etabliert hat, kann man natürlich auch nicht sagen, wie er benutzt oder verstanden wird. (:rhythmisch mit dem Kopf wippend:)

Comment: @userunknown: "Von einem generischen (?), stereotypen Türken war aber nicht die Rede" - als genau so einen verstehe ich den Verweis auf "a Turk" in "Hans writes like a Turk." "vom Schreiben auch nicht" - doch (Hervorhebung durch mich): "Hans **writes** like a Turk."

Comment: @userunknown: "für einen Ausdruck, der sich noch nicht fest etabliert hat, kann man natürlich auch nicht sagen, wie er benutzt oder verstanden wird" - wenn man überhaupt keine Anhaltspunkte hätte, wie ein noch nicht etabliertes Wort verstanden würde, wären spontane Wortbildungen durch Abwandlung bestehender Worte unbrauchbar, da sie ohne beigefügte Definition wohl auf dutzende völlig unterschiedliche Arten interpretiert werden könnten. Aber wie du selbst in einem anderen Kommentar ...

Comment: ... schriebst: "die dt. Sprache ist plastisch und es gehört zu ihrem Wesen, dass sie solche spontanen Wortbildungen zulässt" Das funktioniert eben nur genau dadurch, dass man auch für nicht etablierte Wörter ungefähr abschätzen kann, wie Wörter, die nach einem bestimmten Muster aufgebaut sind, voraussichtlich verstanden werden.